# Check for 4 hours for an wepapi

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis, script-task

I am creating a SSIS package to monitor a service(API) for a json resonse. I am doing this using script task.

That API returns Status: "success" as a JSON element.  I am able to get the result using webclient call from script task.

My question is, if the status is not 'success', I do not want the script task to fail. I want check the API for at least 4 hours and then fail. How do I achieve this?

```
   var startTime = DateTime.Now;

 using (var mySSISWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                mySSISWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept]   = "application/json";
                var result = mySSISWebClient.DownloadString(jsonURLwithDate);  
                var search = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
                var IndexingStatus = search.SearchResponse.STATUS;

                if (IndexingStatus.ToLower() == "success")
                {
                    Dts.Variables["JsonIndexingStatus"].Value = IndexingStatus.ToString();

                    // Quit Script Task succesful
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    Dts.Variables["JsonIndexingStatus"].Value = IndexingStatus.ToString();
                    // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
            }
```

Please help me in writing the for loop to check for 240 minutes from startTime.

Comment: Could you create history to refer to in a later check?

Comment: `var endTime = startTime.AddHours(4); while (DateTime.Now < endTime) { // check the status; // break on success; // sleep for some interval; }`

Comment: What do you mean by sleep for sometime?